# increment of pointer to array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand why the following C++ code does not compile

```cpp
int main () {
  int a[10];
  int (*p)[10] = &a;
  int *q = static_cast<int *>(++p);
}
```

If it's not obvious, what I was trying to do is find a pointer to the end of the array by using pointer arithmetic.

My understanding so far is that `p` has type pointer to array of ten ints and so does the expression `++p`.  Normally, I can assign an array of ints to a variable of type pointer to int but this fails on the incremented pointer `++p`.

I first tried without the `static_cast` but that didn't work either.

Comment: You could make `p` an `int*`: `int* p = a; int* q = ++p;`

Comment: @GregKikola Yes, I could do that, but that's not what I want to do.  I think the pointer arithmetic should be different in the two cases.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted, I didn't see the note about wanting `q` to point to the end of the array. In that case you could do `int *q = a + 10;`. Alternatively, with C++11, `int* q = std::end(a);` (just include `<iterator>`).

Comment: Even if you get this to work, the next person to look at this code will likely not understand it.  I think (a+10) is much clearer.

Comment: @brianbeuning I'm not planning to use this in production code.  I was just playing with pointers...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `p` has type pointer to array of ten ints

This is correct.

> Normally, I can assign an array of ints to a variable of type pointer
>   to int

This is also correct. Except, if you compare your two statements, you should see the obvious difference: `p` is not an array of ints, it is a pointer to an array of ints. Hence, the difference.

Now, if you dereference that pointer to an array, your result will be an expression whose type is an array (loosely speaking), and that can be decayed to a pointer:

```
int *q = static_cast<int *>(*++p);
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: The weird thing is that if I print `p` and `q` I get the same thing.  So there seems to be something weird about pointer arithmetic on pointers to arrays.

Comment: @SidiousLord `p` and `q` are different types, but they hold the same address, both pointing to the element just after the end of the array. `p` points to an array of 10 `int`s starting at that address, `q` points to an `int` at that same address.

Comment: @GregKikola I thing I found my error.  To get what I wanted I need to use `*p++` not `*++p`.  Then `p` will point at the beginning of the array while `q` points to the end of the array.